# Does $\left\{a_n\right\}$ converges to $0$ or $3$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

A sequence $\left\{a_n\right\}$ is defined as, $a_0=2$ and $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{3a_n}$. Find the limit of $a_n$.

Letting $$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=A$$ we have
$$\begin{aligned}
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n+1} &=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{3 a_{n}} \\
A &=\sqrt{3 A}
\end{aligned}$$
$\implies$
$A=0,3$

But how do we decide which is correct?

[https://www.ms.uky.edu/~droyster/ma114F16/RecursiveSequences.pdf](https://www.ms.uky.edu/%7Edroyster/ma114F16/RecursiveSequences.pdf)

The author in this pdf(Page 5) says $A=3$ since he formed a table for a few values of $n$ and observed that it approaches $3$? But is there a formal way to show that $3$ is indeed the limit and not zero?

Comment: figure out if $a_n$ is increasing or decreasing.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that in general, when more than one limit is possible, which one is correct depends on the initial condition $a_0$. Here $a_0 = 2$, which as mentioned in the answers implies that $a_n$ is increasing (and bounded above), hence the limit must be $3$. But if $a_0$ were $0$, then we would have $a_n = 0$ for all $n$, so the limit would be $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You assume that the limit exists, but this must be shown! I leave this as an exercise for you (hint: monotone convergence theorem). What you show is that if a limit exists, it is either $0$ or $3$.

Your sequence is increasing, so in particular $a_n \ge 2$ for all $n$. Hence, it is impossible that the limit is $0$.

Comment: It doesn't have to be shown _first_, but it must be shown. Some times it's easier to show that the limit exists when you know what it ought to be. So _not_ showing it first but instead showing it _last_ can actually be advantageous.

Comment: What if the sequence were decreasing with values of $A$ as $0,1$?

Comment: @Umeshshankar What if.. This is not the case here.

Comment: @Arthur Yes I agree.

Comment: @Arthur, as per your comment we need to show at last that $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ exists right? but since $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=3$, and $3$ is finite, so does it not got automatically proved? Or should we prove $3$ is indeed the limit using $\epsilon-N$ approach?

Comment: @Umeshshankar In your approach, you assume that the limit exists (you denote it by $A$). How do you know that there exists a real number $A$ with $\lim_n a_n = A$ without showing that this exists first?

Comment: Yes i completely agree with your point, but my comment is about Arthur's way of approach. Now according to you, we actually need to show that the sequence is bounded above and hence by MCT it converges.

Comment: @Umesshankar As an illustrative example, take the sequence $b_{n+1}=b_n^2$, with $b_0=2$. Your approach tells you that the limit has to be $0$ or $1$, but in this case the limit doesn't exist. You have to prove that something similar doesn't happen to your $a_n$. All I'm saying is that proving that the limit exists, and calculating what the limit is, are two separate things that can be done independently and in any order. And in fact, some times the existence is easier to prove afterwards rather than before calculating the limit value.

Comment: Your example is quite obvious since it is increasing from $2$, so both the limits $0,1$ not possible. But in my sequence this is not the situation right, because i got a limit $3>2$, so $3$ is indeed the limit. Now you said existence is easier to prove afterwards. So my point is should we use $\epsilon-N$ approach? Also I am really not sure how to prove increasing sequence is bounded above.

Comment: @Umeshshakar It is _sometimes_ easier to prove afterwards, exactly because an $\varepsilon$-$N$ proof becomes viable. But when MCT works, that's easier.

Comment: Thanku Arthur and Quantum...I figured out using MCT that the limit exists and hence my assumption makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you can prove that there exists by induction that there exists some $\epsilon>0$ such that $a_n>\epsilon$ for all $n$ that would be enough. For example, if $a_{n+1}\geq a_n$ for all $n$, then
$$  a_n\geq2>0. $$
In your case, I think you can show that $2\leq a_n\leq 3$ for all $n$, which would show this.